# How to set the "swfURL" field value in ActionScript?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I have written a Flash application in ActionScript, and in this application I have to connect to a Flash Server. 
I have this problem: the server refuses the connection because the value of the "swfURL" field in the RTMP protocol is undefined. I don't understand why the application is not setting this value, because "swfURL" is the value of the source file. 
And I don't find any method in the Flash API to change the value of this parameter. 
The code is something like this:

```
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netStatusHandler);
nc.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, securityErrorHandler);

ncDomain = IP ADDRESS;
ncPort = PORT;
ncApplication = APPLICATION;

url = "rtmp://" + ncDomain + ":" + ncPort + "/" + ncApplication;
nc.connect(url);
```

EDIT:
I tell you more details:
I use the "FlashDevelop" IDE to write the program. I use the debugger of the IDE to execute the program, and the swfURL has the value "undefined" when I see the packets with Wireshark. 
I also try to put my application in a web page, using "swfobject" in JavaScript, like this:

```
<script src="js/swfobject.js"></script>
<script>
    var flashvars = {
    };
    var params = {
        menu: "false",
        scale: "noScale",
        allowFullscreen: "true",
        allowScriptAccess: "always",
        bgcolor: "",
        wmode: "direct" // can cause issues with FP settings & webcam
    };
    var attributes = {
        id:"Proyecto"
    };
    swfobject.embedSWF(
        "Proyecto.swf", 
        "altContent", "100%", "100%", "10.0.0", 
        "expressInstall.swf", 
        flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

And doing this, the problem is the same, the value of "swfURL" is undefined, and it must be "Proyecto.swf", as you see in the code above, where it says "swfobject.embedSWF". 
I don't understand why, when my application connects to the server, it doesn't send the url of the sender: the value of swfURL in the RTMP protocol.

Comment: You have to look in your FMS server to see how the server is waiting for that info. It's possible to pass it directly in the connection url as a param or using the `NetConnection.connect()` function, or using a server side function, ...

Comment: I can't view the code of the server. I only know that if the "swfURL" value in the RTMP protocol is different to "undefined", it works. I checked this by using Wireshark.

Comment: Are you speaking about the referrer ?

Comment: Yes, it's something like that. The file that makes the connection is called "project.swf". So the "swfURL" value must be "project.swf". But, this is the problem, "swfURL" takes the value "undefined", and the server refuses the connection for security I think. It seems to be like you make a HTTP petition to a HTTP server and the "user agent" label is not set: most HTTP servers refuses the connection by security.

Comment: Yes exactly, like HTTP headers for HTTP request, the problem is that value is sent by Flash Player I think, so you have nothing that you can do. But you didn't tell us, in which case it's not sent ? Which Flash Player versions ? Which browsers ? ... any information can help to know the origin of the problem.

Comment: I have edited my question above with more details.